# VMware Tools install fails on SLES 10 SP4 x64

Tags: vmware-player, suse

I installed SLES 10 SP4 64 bit in VMWare Player 7.1.0 and tried to install the VMWare tools.

From the CD I extracted VMwareTools-9.9.2-2496486.tar.gz (as running run_upgrader.sh fails...) and started *vmware-install.pl* which starts *bin/vmware-config-tools.pl* that fails with:

```
Searching for GCC...
sh: line 1: 18379 Floating point exception'/usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmware-modconfig-console' --validate-gcc "" -- -l "/usr/lib/vmware-tools" >/dev/null 2>&1
The path "" is not valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [yes]

What is the location of the gcc program on your machine? /usr/bin/gcc

sh: line 1: 18384 Floating point exception'/usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmware-modconfig-console' --validate-gcc "/usr/bin/gcc" -- -l "/usr/lib/vmware-tools" >/dev/null 2>&1
The path "/usr/bin/gcc" is not valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

I installed make, gcc, c++ (g++), kernel-source and Basis-Devel, but something is still missing.

What is bothering it? Wrong perl version? I have 5.8.8 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have libglib-2_0-0 installed?  Perhaps the commands 'whereis gcc'  or 'which gcc'  commands could provide more information.  I'm not very familiar with SLES,  but hopefully this will help.

Edit: VMware Tools may be available as a package. Try searching for open-vm-tools or vmware tools using your pkg manager. Also, check out VMware's [OS specific repositories](http://packages.vmware.com/tools).

Comment: I installed glib2 (and later also glib) it does not help. /usr/bin/gcc is the actual location, also returned by "type gcc".

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the Guest OS Customization Support Matrix:
http://partnerweb.vmware.com/programs/guestOS/guest-os-customization-matrix.pdf

Seems that you're using an not supported SuSE Release (< 10SP4).
Upgrade at least to SLES10 SP4 / SLES11 SP4

Comment: On the link it says SLES 10 SP4 is supported. And I am using it, as stated in the question.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.